# Error opening block database Full node

Tags: bitcoin-core, full-node, leveldb

For some reason my node shutdown and now I get when restart it

```
Error opening block database
```

here my bitcoin.conf

```
txindex=1
reindex=1
reindex-chainstate=1      
# Accept command line and JSON-RPC commands.
server=1
# Options only for mainnet
[main]
# Options only for testnet
[test]
# Options only for regtest
[regtest]
```

this is my debug.log

```
2020-08-29T07:17:24Z Bitcoin Core version v0.19.1 (release build)
2020-08-29T07:17:24Z Assuming ancestors of block 00000000000000000005f8920febd3925f8272a6a71237563d78c2edfdd09ddf have valid signatures.
2020-08-29T07:17:24Z Setting nMinimumChainWork=000000000000000000000000000000000000000008ea3cf107ae0dec57f03fe8
2020-08-29T07:17:24Z Using the 'standard' SHA256 implementation
2020-08-29T07:17:24Z Default data directory /home/bitcoin/.bitcoin
2020-08-29T07:17:24Z Using data directory /home/bitcoin/.bitcoin
2020-08-29T07:17:24Z Config file: /home/bitcoin/.bitcoin/bitcoin.conf
2020-08-29T07:17:24Z Using at most 125 automatic connections (1024 file descriptors available)
2020-08-29T07:17:24Z Using 16 MiB out of 32/2 requested for signature cache, able to store 524288 elements
2020-08-29T07:17:24Z Using 16 MiB out of 32/2 requested for script execution cache, able to store 524288 elements
2020-08-29T07:17:24Z Using 4 threads for script verification
2020-08-29T07:17:24Z HTTP: creating work queue of depth 16
2020-08-29T07:17:24Z No rpcpassword set - using random cookie authentication.
2020-08-29T07:17:24Z scheduler thread start
2020-08-29T07:17:24Z Generated RPC authentication cookie /home/bitcoin/.bitcoin/.cookie
2020-08-29T07:17:24Z HTTP: starting 4 worker threads
2020-08-29T07:17:24Z Using wallet directory /home/bitcoin/.bitcoin
2020-08-29T07:17:24Z init message: Verifying wallet(s)...
2020-08-29T07:17:24Z Using BerkeleyDB version Berkeley DB 4.8.30: (April  9, 2010)
2020-08-29T07:17:24Z Using wallet /home/bitcoin/.bitcoin
2020-08-29T07:17:24Z BerkeleyEnvironment::Open: LogDir=/home/bitcoin/.bitcoin/database ErrorFile=/home/bitcoin/.bitcoin/db.log
2020-08-29T07:17:24Z init message: Loading banlist...
2020-08-29T07:17:24Z Cache configuration:
2020-08-29T07:17:24Z * Using 2.0 MiB for block index database
2020-08-29T07:17:24Z * Using 56.0 MiB for transaction index database
2020-08-29T07:17:24Z * Using 8.0 MiB for chain state database
2020-08-29T07:17:24Z * Using 384.0 MiB for in-memory UTXO set (plus up to 286.1 MiB of unused mempool space)
2020-08-29T07:17:24Z init message: Loading block index...
2020-08-29T07:17:24Z LevelDB using max_open_files=64 (default=1000)
2020-08-29T07:17:24Z Wiping LevelDB in /home/bitcoin/.bitcoin/blocks/index
2020-08-29T07:17:24Z Opening LevelDB in /home/bitcoin/.bitcoin/blocks/index
2020-08-29T07:17:24Z leveldb: Delete type=3 #1
2020-08-29T07:17:24Z Opened LevelDB successfully
2020-08-29T07:17:24Z Using obfuscation key for /home/bitcoin/.bitcoin/blocks/index: 0000000000000000
2020-08-29T07:17:24Z WriteBatch memory usage: db=index, before=0.0MiB, after=0.0MiB
2020-08-29T07:17:24Z Initializing databases...
2020-08-29T07:17:24Z LevelDB using max_open_files=64 (default=1000)
2020-08-29T07:17:24Z Wiping LevelDB in /home/bitcoin/.bitcoin/chainstate
2020-08-29T07:17:24Z Fatal LevelDB error: IO error: /home/bitcoin/.bitcoin/chainstate/449175.ldb: Bad message
2020-08-29T07:17:24Z You can use -debug=leveldb to get more complete diagnostic messages
2020-08-29T07:17:24Z Fatal LevelDB error: IO error: /home/bitcoin/.bitcoin/chainstate/449175.ldb: Bad message
2020-08-29T07:17:24Z Error: Error opening block database
Error: Error opening block database
2020-08-29T07:17:24Z Shutdown: In progress...
2020-08-29T07:17:24Z scheduler thread interrupt
2020-08-29T07:17:24Z Shutdown: done
```

Comment: As said in the log, "You can use -debug=leveldb to get more complete diagnostic messages".. Also, an IO error is very likely hardware-related.

Comment: @darosior thanks for the reply, with -debug=leveldb I don't have more information. I Can access and write without problem on my HDD